# Google Maps API - KML OnClick Not Showing For Some Recently Changed Polygons/Layers

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

Let me start by saying I am not a coder by any means however I have managed to get my KML working via the Google Maps API. I then made some changes to the KML via Google Earth and uploaded the new file to our webserver. Now when you click on the changed areas, the onClick event fails to fire/the information is just not there. Site is: http://www.dynamicbradview.com.au/regionalmap.html

Code snip below and as mentioned, this is working for some of the regions but not the recently changed ones. Any ideas for where I am going wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dynamic Bradview Roofing Regional Supervisors Map</title>
<style>
      html,
   body {
        height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 5;
        background-color: #B0D136;
        }
      #map {
       height: 97%;
       width: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
       }
      #capture {
       top: 10px;
       left: 50%;
       z-index: 5;
       padding: 5px;
       text-align: center;
       font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
       line-height: 30px;
       padding-left: 10px;
       }
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="capture"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
     <script>
      var map;
      var src = 'http://www.dynamicbradview.com.au/images/SupervisorRegionalMap.kml';
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
          var content = event.featureData.infoWindowHtml;
          var testimonial = document.getElementById('capture');
          testimonial.innerHTML = content;
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDEckKvcigtRb1k2BsRwLdhmF5E_8O0JNg&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the recently changed regions that aren't working correctly?  Note that Google's servers cache the KML for some period of time (a few hours), if you need it to show up immediately, you need to add a cache busting parameter to the URL of your file.

Comment: It is the purple, red, and orange zones that were changed and now not working. It has also been several days since the changes were made but the site is definitely not displaying them. I have even added an additional polygon to test and this is also not displaying.

And can you please expand on the final comment (I am a complete beginner here). What is a cache-busting parameter?

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip I did some research and updating the KML filename with versioning resolved it immediately! I need to stick to networking and server infrastructure I think! 

Next step is to improve the map configuration so it is a bit more user friendly and possibly have hover text instead of click (if possible!). Thanks again mate.